# Vb.net How to count hours between two times

Tags: vb.net, datetime, calculation

first of all, the question I ask is very difficult to ask for me, because my english is not that good.

Im while making a program, that takes values from my other program and then does some calculation with that data. To give you a better imagination of it I will explain how it works. A technician is working 7,5 hours a day. He works between 7:30 AM and 4:00 PM(There is a break between 12:00-12:30). Between this time period, a customer pays 88,00 Euro per hour. If the technician has the need to stay longer, after 4:00 PM the customer will have to pay 110,00 Euro per hour, after 10:00 PM 132,00 Euro and from 10:00 Pm until 06:00 AM 176,00 Euro.
From my other programm I get values like:

Working from-until

If the day is a holiday( if true the customer will pay independent the timing 176,00 Euro per hour.

Lunch (If true, 30 minutes are subtracted)

My question is: How can I calculate the hours with different prices depending of the time?
First i though to convert time into decimals to get the hours,  but then i realized that i don't know how to do it. I would be really thankful for some advices & tips.
For more information please comment and I will try my best.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're in Vb.Net you can use all the .Net tools like `DateTime` and `Timespan` for time calculations :

```
Dim startTime = New DateTime(2001, 1, 1, 10, 0, 0)
Dim endTime = New DateTime(2001, 1, 1, 10, 30, 0)

Dim duration = endTime - startTime
Dim durationInHour = duration.TotalHours
```